# Android : Marquee app name

Tags: android

I am new to android. I have developed simple app for android. But the things is my app name is having 3 words. So I want to apply marquee property for my app name. I mean, when I install my app on device so that it appears in app category/menu. Currently it is static, so it should be having marquee property, so my app name gets move continuously from right to left like textview in android. So can anyone plz tell me how I can achieve this thing in android?

Comment: As answered below, generally you cannot modify launcher's behavior, including adding marquee to the app name (unless you're using/developing custom launcher). Instead, it's recommended to use short name for the launcher, while you can use full name as the title inside the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this would require a change to the Android code itself. However, if you want to do this in your app, you could try adding `android:ellipsize="marquee"` to your textviews.

Comment: Actually you didn't get my question. I want to apply it for app name, not to textview. I know how to use it for textview. If you are still confused plz let me know. I'll clear it.

Comment: So you want to apply a marquee to the app name in the actionbar or on the users homescreen and/or app drawer?

Comment: Ya I want to apply it for home screen app name.

Comment: As mentioned in my answer, you would have to talk to Google or make a custom ROM that allowed this. It's not possible to overwrite the Android homescreen or app drawer. As Andrew T. stated too, try making a short app name and then using a longer one for the action bar.

Comment: No problem! Make sure to mark answers that have helped you using the check mark.